# Change the behaviour of chrome extension to a perticular url only

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

Hello this is my manifest.json file.

```
   {
  "name": "Injecta",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Injecting stuff",
   "homepage_url": "http://danharper.me",
    "background": {
    "scripts": [
     "background.js"
     ],
      "persistent": true
       },
       "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Inject!"
         },

        "permissions": [
         "https://*/*",
         "http://*/*",
         "tabs"
         ]
         }
```

inject.js

```
      (function() {
     var charsTyped = [];
       document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
       evt = evt || window.event;
     var charCode = typeof evt.which == "number" ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode) {
       charsTyped.push(String.fromCharCode(charCode));
          alert(charsTyped);
        }
        };
        })();



      // this is the background code...

        // listen for our browerAction to be clicked
       chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
          chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
        });
        });
```

This is working great but only thing that i need to do is to run this extension only for specific domains like google or something..

i tried adding the match url but it gives me errors

Comment: You could use some code formatting to make it easier for anyone to help you, or even better post your properly formatted code on https://jsfiddle.net or similar service.

Comment: exactly what errors you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: The following section refers to the old question before it was totally changed in an edit:**

It says it right there.

> Invalid value for 'content_scripts'.

That's your problem. Take a look at the [example in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) and compare...

Yep, the problem is that you don't define any `js`/`css` but you defined `matches` (which will do nothing and just cause the error). If you don't use content scripts, then remove the `content_scripts` section altogether.

---

**This section refers to the new question:**

You are mixing things together and I'm amazed that it kinda-sorta works, probably because the background page has a DOM as well, and when you inject the same script in a web page, it will appear to work because the unavoidable crash at `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` happens after the actual work is already done.

So, first thing you should do: Create two files. One is the background script, one is the content script. They do two different things and run with different privileges as well. In your background script, you have the `browserAction` part which injects your content script then.

If your content script should always be running, then the way to go would be removing the background page and using the `content_scripts` value instead, with `matches` and `js`. However, since you want it to be injected only when the button is clicked, it has to be done the way I described in the previous paragraph. Now to check if the page is the one you like, all you need to do is to check [the `url` property of your `tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-Tab-url). You can of course stuff it into a `URL` object then and access its properties.

For example: `if(new URL(tab.url).hostname == "google.com") doSomething()`

Oh and you should definitely indent your code and manifest properly. Just stuff it into an online JavaScript beautifier to see the difference.